# How to give time instead of angle in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular8

Hi i am working on highcharts i am having a polar chart and i wanna display on y-axis time instead of angle. This is the one which i tried so far:

In x-axis i am having angle and i have given `tickInterval: 45,` so in the same way how to do this for time.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    polar: true
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Also known as Radar Chart'
},

pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360
},

xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 45,
    min: 0,
    max: 360,
    labels: {
        format: '{value}°'
    }
},

yAxis: {
    min: 0
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: 0,
        pointInterval: 45
    },
    column: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0
    }
},

series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Column',
    data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    pointPlacement: 'between'
}, {
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Line',
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}]
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t3zs9re8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is the same as in a non-polar chart. You can use `datetime` axis type and data in `[x, y]` format.

It is also possible to use categories, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L5p6krvd/

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            [new Date('2020-5-12').getTime(), 115],
            [new Date('2020-5-13').getTime(), 50],
            ...
        ]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pv0zm2ky/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type